# как спарсить дату?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

немогу спарсить дату с сайта `https://directlot.ru/products.php` (дата размещения заказа)

выводит значение none
я вставил этот кусок кода потомучто название спарсилось, а вот время немогу
спарсить надо это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

исходник:(я пытался вывести "в коде это data")

```
def parser():
    HOST = "https://directlot.ru"
    URL = 'https://directlot.ru/products.php'
    HEADERS = {'User_Agent': user}

    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS,)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_='lotListOneLotCompA')
    count = 0
    comps = []
    for item in items:
        gorodok = item.find('div', class_='lotListOneLotParam')
        datka = gorodok.find('span', class_='lotListOneLotParamOu')

        count += 1
        comps.append({
            'title': item.find('a', class_='lotListOneLotHeadCompA').get_text(strip=True),
            'price': item.find('td', class_='lotListOneLotCenaCompA').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': HOST + item.find('a', class_='lotListOneLotHeadCompA').get('href'),
            'blago': item.find('td', class_='lotListOneLotProdParamNum').get_text(strip=True),
            'name': item.find('div', class_='lotListOneLotProdName').get_text(strip=True),
            'gorod': gorodok.find_all('span')[1].get_text(strip=True),
            'data': gorodok.find('span', class_='lotListOneLotParamOu').get('title'),
        })
```

Comment: я открыл ссылку, совершенно непонятно. что там должно парситься

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте, [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), т.к. в текущем состоянии на вопрос невозможно ответить. Ваш код вырван их контекста,  и мы не можем понять, что происходит в целом.

Comment: @Эникейщик я исправил, вопрос стал понятен?

Comment: @Marlin09, добавьте кусок html (текстом), в котором дата хранится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел, как хранится дата, ее нужно смотреть в атрибуте `title` тега `span`:

```
<span title="26.08.2021, 18:39 | unixtime: 1629985170" id="ti0odl" onclick="return directlot_ShowTimeAddModChg(0)">56 сек. назад</span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно только его спарсить, например:

```
import datetime as DT
import re

title = "26.08.2021, 18:39 | unixtime: 1629985170"
m = re.search(r'unixtime: (\d+)', title)
unix_time = int(m.group(1))

print(DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time))
# 2021-08-26 18:39:30
```

**UPD.**

Там рендеринг HTML

Поменял функцию:

```
def get_datetime(title: str) -> DT.datetime:
    m = re.search(r'directlot_ShowTimeAddMod\((\d+)', title)
    unix_time = int(m.group(1))
    return DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time)
```

С вашим кодом:

```
HOST = "https://directlot.ru"
URL = HOST + '/products.php'
HEADERS = {'User_Agent': ''}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
items = soup.findAll('div', class_='lotListOneLotCompA')
count = 0
comps = []
for item in items:
    gorodok = item.find('div', class_='lotListOneLotParam')
    datka = gorodok.find('span', class_='lotListOneLotParamOu')

    count += 1
    comps.append({
        'title': item.find('a', class_='lotListOneLotHeadCompA').get_text(strip=True),
        'price': item.find('td', class_='lotListOneLotCenaCompA').get_text(strip=True),
        'link': HOST + item.find('a', class_='lotListOneLotHeadCompA').get('href'),
        'blago': item.find('td', class_='lotListOneLotProdParamNum').get_text(strip=True),
        'name': item.find('div', class_='lotListOneLotProdName').get_text(strip=True),
        'gorod': gorodok.find_all('span')[1].get_text(strip=True),
        'data': get_datetime(str(datka)),
    })
```

Comment: ты перевел дату в привычный и понятный вид, но я хотел бы чтобы в консоль выводились все даты (каждого обявления)

Comment: @Marlin09, сделаете в парсере перебор всех объявлений, вытащите из каждого объявления атрибут `title` и примените код из ответа :)

Comment: он выдает мне none. Можно код, может кдето делаю ошибку

Comment: @Marlin09, а похоже, тот тег рендерится через javascript и недоступен. Вывел что пришло с сайта: `<span class="lotListOneLotParamOu">
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
directlot_ShowTimeAddMod(1629989846, "назад");
// --></script>
</span>`

Comment: @Marlin09, обновил ответ, проверьте